# Where to declare variables used in application (wxWidgets)?

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I've created `MyApp` class which inherit from `wxApp` and added some component variables to it:

```cpp
class MyApp : public wxApp {
    GameBoard* gb;
    Player* player;
    bool lightTheme;

    std::vector<wxBitmapToggleButton *> cardImages;
public:
    MyApp();
    virtual bool OnInit();
    void displayImages(wxFrame *, wxGridSizer *);

    void OnCardSelect(wxCommandEvent&);
};
```

then I set their values in `MyApp::OnInit`:

```cpp
void MyApp::OnInit() {
    //...
    player = new Player(1);
    //...
}
```

and when I use `Player` class methods in `MyApp::OnInit` function, everything works fine, but when I use it in event function, I'm getting strange results (for example size of **empty** `std::vector<int>` declared in `Player` class returns 18446744073709551540). Event function:

```cpp
void MyApp::OnCardSelect(wxCommandEvent& event) {
    std::cout << (player->getChosen()).size() << std::endl;
    // above line only for debugging, getChosen() returns const std::vector<int>&, which should be empty, but it print strange result
    wxBitmapToggleButton *selectedCard = dynamic_cast<wxBitmapToggleButton *>(event.GetEventObject());
    player -> toggleChosen(int(selectedCard -> GetId()));
}
```

What is happening with component variables of `MyApp` after calling `OnInit` (using `IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)`), and where should I declare and change values of these varables?

Comment: Are you calling `OnInit` function before `OnCardSelect` function? It seems, that `OnCardSelect` function was invoked before `OnInit` function, so `player` is not initialized yet

Comment: To be sure, simply log some strings from both functions

Comment: The code as shown can't compile, you can't use `player` field of `MyApp` without the object.

Comment: I think `OnInit` is called using `IMPLEMENT_APP`. `OnCardSelect` is connected to button event (and called only when it is clicked), and button is created in `OnInit` function, so `Player` object should be already created.